# Chrome Driver and selenium webdriver in protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Google Chrome version 60. While configuring protractor, which Chrome driver and Selenium web-driver version should I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use the latest ones.. should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Use latest one

- ChromeDriver 2.32 from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
- Selenium jar 3.5.1 from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)